# Trigger Error(14,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following: := . ( % ;

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I have this trigger

```
create or replace
trigger trg_cust
after insert or update on nbty_customer
referencing old as old new as new
for each row
declare
sal_diff number;
begin
if(:new.cust_sal>:old.cust_sal)
then
update nbty_cache_cust set cust_nbty_sal=:new.cust_sal where cust_nbty_id=:old.cust_id;
elseif(:new.cust_sal<:old.cust_sal)
then
update nbty_cache_cust set cust_nbty_sal=:old.cust_sal+:new.cust_sal where cust_nbty_id=:old.cust_id;
end if;
end;
```

But this is throwing

```
Error(14,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( % ;
```

I am not getting what is wrong in this kindly help

Comment: Just a small off topic question. Why you don't like formatted codes?

Comment: i dont know how to format it here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: thank you..will use it from next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use keyword `elsif` instead of `elseif`